Can't create Sierra installer - installing macOS gives a bug with -200 Seconds
I tried to download macOS Sierra from Apple’s website, but because my new MacBook is on Sonoma, I can’t run the Sierra package to create a bootable USB flash drive like it’s mentioned by Apple.
I also can’t run the installer on my old MacBook on which I want to install Sierra, because it can only boot in recovery mode.
How can I create a Sierra installer or otherwise install Sierra on my old MacBook?

Why are you trying to run the installer on a machine other than the one you want to install on?

I though i can make a bootable usb stick

Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried installing macOS from Recovery? Start up your old Mac and, in the window that appears, you should see an option named "Reinstall macOS " (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/102655#reinstall for details). If you don't see that option, start your old Mac and press and hold Option-Command-R. With this key combination, Recovery will offer the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/102655#startup for details).

The "minus seconds" are appearing in the recovery Mode-Installation

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275

If your Mac is M1 or later then it won't run the Sierra install package as it is not written for ARM processors.

The Mac i want to run sierra on ist an old macbook air, which is compatible with sierra

@Jamie_Gerber but you state: "but because my new MacBook is on Sonoma, I can’t run the Sierra package like it’s mentioned by Apple"

Yes, on it I tried to download the installer package

If both options you are trying are failing..I think the easiest way would be to create a USB installer on another Sierra compatible Mac. These are the
Sierra compatible Macs :
MacBook (Late 2009 to 2017)
MacBook Air (Late 2010 to 2017, which is same as 2015 model)
MacBook Pro (Mid 2010 to 2015)
Mac mini (Mid 2010 to 2014)
iMac (Late 2009 to 2015)
Mac Pro (Mid 2010 and 2013)

Use this page for instructions if you are not already :https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662        :)
